# How to sync content between drupal staging env and production env?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, content-management-system, migration

We are facing typical migration related issue with drupal 7.  Our portal is hosted in two env. a. staging b. production.

a. Staging : Here developer installs new modules, create views, change settings.  Site has many view comps.
b. Production: Here client add/edit content most of the time.

How do we migrate our content from staging to production without loosing content?

Please help.

Regards

Comment: What exactly do you need to sync. between the two sites?

Answer (score 0):

You can export the views to code on your staging environment and then update the code on production. You can get the detailed explanation here:

http://www.deckfifty.com/blog/2012-02/using-drupal-views-code

Answer (score 0):

You can sync. most of a site configuration by exporting it to code, then managing your deployment.
See the following links:

- http://developmentseed.org/blog/2009/jul/09/development-staging-production-workflow-problem-drupal/
- http://www.slideshare.net/nuvoleweb/code-driven-development-using-features-effectively-in-drupal-6-and-7
- http://www.bluesparklabs.com/blog/drupal-configuration-management-features
- http://nuvole.org/blog/2011/jan/13/five-reasons-code-driven-development-and-features-are-good-you

Answer (score 0):

We use the features module https://www.drupal.org/project/features to do it. Very easy to manage multiple environments by creating a feature and then importing it in your prod environment. There are tutorials at the bottom of the drupal.org page.